# QEMU command with NVME boot is functional but cannot convert to virt-install parameters

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, libvirt

I'm attempting to convert a working qemu command to virt-install parameters.  The working command is:

`qemu-system-x86_64 -bios /usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd -boot c -drive file=/vm/image.qcow2,if=none,id=NVME1 -device nvme,drive=NVME1,serial=nvme-1 -m 4G -cpu host -enable-kvm`

...what I **thought** was a 1-to-1 translation into with virt-install ends up with an error:

`sudo virt-install --boot loader=/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd --boot cdrom,hd --disk none --qemu-commandline='-drive file=/vm/image.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=NVME1 -device nvme,drive=NVME1,serial=nvme-1' --memory 4096 --os-variant rhel9.0 --name Test`

This results in this error:

`Starting install... ERROR    internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2023-06-01T00:16:40.801184Z qemu-system-x86_64: -drive file=/vm/image.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=NVME1: Could not open '/vm/image.qcow2': Permission denied.`

`Domain installation does not appear to have been successful. If it was, you can restart your domain by running: virsh --connect qemu:///system start Test otherwise, please restart your installation.`

I'm stumped.  I'm a QEMU/KVM/libvirt newbie, so I've been deep in the docs but to no avail.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /vm /vm/image.qcow2`?

Comment: Forgot to mention that i set it to chmod 777 out of desperation.

Comment: Why didn't you just do what I asked? Now I have to ask a second question for the same information because it is unclear whether that `777` refers to the file, to the directory or to both...